# How to get current document node in Autodesk Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there any way to get the current `name` and `guid` of document node that is displayed by viewer from `NOP_VIEWER`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `doc = NOP_VIEWER.model.getDocumentNode()`

where `doc.guid` and `doc.name` contains what you need

doc...

```
guid: "7c752bce-db6d-e2bc-5c47-b6a90cbe8cfa"
hasThumbnail: "true"
name: "New Construction"
phaseNames: "New Construction"
progress: "complete"
role: "3d"
size: 18529526
status: "success"
success: "100%"
type: "geometry"
viewableID: "c884ae1b-61e7-4f9d-0001-719e20b22d0b-000f3c60"
```